# Why is my marigold drooping

Tags: diseases

Just a couple of hours ago my marigold was fine, the next time I saw it.... It had its leaves dropping, soil dry but the flowers were fine. The two leaves at the beginning of the stem are starting to yellow and just watered it.. will it be ok?

Comment: Can you water it, wait a few hours and add a picture?

Comment: where are you in the world, and what type of marigold is it?